# HAProxy multiple frontend/listeners

Tags: web-services, load-balancing, web-hosting, haproxy, high-availability

I want to use one HAProxy host to direct traffic from multiple frontend/listener IPs to respective backends.
Is there any way to easily accomplish this on Debian/Centos host?

Not using dcoker or anything else, just installing haproxy to offload tcp connections to multiple other servers.
All the information I have read either directs me to ACLs, which would be extreme as we have thousands of domains spread across a number of 'backend' servers, or shows the listener on ' * ' which is any, of course.

We were using cisco switch load balancing and now want to do the work in VMs with easy to digest monitoring of the requests to various servers, adding and removing resources as we need.

HAProxy starts fine and in the netstat -pln shows the service on each of the IPs we had configured in the load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is painfully simple:
On debian based systems:
Configure your /etc/network/interfaces file to use virtual network interfaces with something like:

```
# The primary or physical network interface
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.10
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.0.1
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

# first virtual interface
auto eth0:0
allow-hotplug eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.11
    netmask 255.255.255.0

# second virtual interface
auto eth0:1
allow-hotplug eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
    address 192.168.0.12
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```